# Reinstall npm yo ionic error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, yeoman-generator

I fiddled with npm to reinstall it from scratch because of dependency issues, so I ran `rm -rf ~/.npm`

Then ran `npm install -g npm`
Then `npm install -g chai mocha yo generator-ionic`
The last install failed for generator-ionic with the following error:

```
npm WARN generator-ionic@0.8.0 requires a peer of yo@>=1.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-8ba0f614
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-8ba0f614' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-8ba0f614' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-ionic/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/donjohnson/ionic-nom/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

If I run `yo ionic` the following error occurs:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'child-process-close'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-ionic/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:15:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-ionic/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:518:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
```

I'm fairly certain I messed the file structure but I have no idea how to fix it or how to properly remove all the components to start from scratch.

Comment: did you try `npm install child-process-close` ?

Comment: tried it, not changing the result :(

Comment: it seems like you've messed up your nodejs dependency linking. Clean everything and re-install nodejs/npm again.

Comment: @ohyeahthatssour Did you get past this? I am getting the exact same error and your findings might help me resolve this. I just reinstalled NPM using brew and ran into this issue... earlier I was getting this error: